# How to generate tables from entities in Idea 13?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipselink

Im giving idea a try and cant find the option JPA>Generate table from entities. I come from the eclipse world where I can generate entities or script with a couple of clicks and I find this is harder to do in  intellij.

This is the persistence.xml I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="hmdb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hmdb_dev"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="appsetup"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="--------"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="/home/jhonnytunes/Projects/hmdb/target" />
        <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="create.sql" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The location Im using to generate the files is the idea build dir. Isn't there a way to generate using the eclipselink that you download from the eclipselink page as a zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the DDL-scripts at server startup with this in persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="/sql" />
  <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="create.sql" />
</properties>
```

Values for the first property can be

- create-tables
- create-or-extend-tables
- drop-and-create-tables
- none

And for the second property

- database
- sql-script
- both

More info in the eclipselink documentation for example [here](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm) and [here](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation_output_mode.htm#BABCDHBB).

Comment: I will try that tonight with tomcat7.

Comment: It didnt work. I restart tomcat @ intellij and cant find any sql script.

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to create the tables, not the script. You should be able to control that with the second option, I'll update the answer

Comment: Nice, I tried that option, but without the filename attribute in the xml. I guess that was the reason it didnt work. I'll try again this night.

Comment: Alright hope it works, I don't have IntelliJ so can't check, but these are the basic principles. Maybe the location-value `"/sql"` is platform- and/or IDE specific, so you might have to experiment with that

Comment: Didnt work. Intellij is so hard to use with jpa for 200 bucks.

Comment: Do you have the persistence-unit correctly set up in persistence.xml? If not you're not using eclipselink at all. Otherwise I'm out of ideas sorry

Comment: I will update my question with the persistence.xml file.

Comment: It works. When I restart the tomcat instance in intellij idea I have to wait about 5 minutes for the script to appear. Thank.